# Loop recursively into subfolders and look for a substring into files

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, substring

I would like to create a script that loops reccursively through subfolders of `D:\MyFolder\` for example, to find multiple files named `MyFile.txt`
then look into each file for the keyword `FROM` and retrieve the string between the `FROM` and the next semicolon `;`.

Sample of `MyFile.txt`:

> ```
> LOAD
>    Thing1,
>    Thing2,
>    Thing3,
> FROM
>    Somewhere ;
> ```

The desired result is: `Somewhere`.

(The position of the semicolon `;` can be in another line).

I did some tries but I did not succeed in writing a correct script:

```
@echo off
SET PATH="D:\MyFolder\"
FOR /R %PATH% %%f IN (MyFile.txt) DO (
    FOR /F "delims=FROM eol=;" %%A in (%%f) do (
    set str=%%A
    ECHO %str% 
    )
)
```

If it can't be done in batch, please let me know in which language I can do it easily. I would like to have an executable script in the end.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Findstr

Comment: The `delims` option of `for /F` defines _characters_ but not _words_ to be used as delimiter for parsing text files; use [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.com) to retrieve the position (line number, option `/N`) of the keyword `FROM`; could the string between `FROM` and `;` comprise multiple lines? if so, simply concatenate them? is there always a single occurrence of `FROM` per file?

Comment: I tried to use findstr but it is not recongnised when I execute the script, "findstr is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Yes the string between `FROM` and `;` can be in multiple lines. There is multiple occurrence of `FROM` in each file.

Comment: I believe, you messed up your `%path%` variable... Don't use `%path%` as a variable name - it's used by `cmd` to find it's executables.

Comment: @Believer, `findstr` is not found as you are modifying the variable `PATH` used by the system; use another variable name. Is every `FROM` keyword in its own separate line, or may it be followed by some text? how to return multi-line text in between `FROM` and `;`? also return as multi-line text?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes indeed, by modifying my variable name, the command "findstr" is recognized. The word "FROM" can either be in a separate line or followed by text. In fact the parsed file is a code file, and depending on the organization of the code by the developer the word "FROM" can be written separately on a line or followed by text. Same thing for the semicolon. The multi-line text should be concatenated, I would like to log it into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

- The `delims` option of `for /F` defines *characters* but *not words* to be used as delimiter for parsing text files. To find a word, use `findstr` instead (you could use its `/N` option to derive the position/line number of the search string).
- The `eol` option of `for /F` defines a character to ignore a line in case it occurs at the beginning (or it is preceded by delimiters only).
- `for /R` does actually not search for files in case there are no wild-cards (`?`, `*`) in the set (that is the part in between parentheses). The `dir /S` command does, so you can work around this by wrapping a `for /F` loop around `dir /S`.
- The `PATH` variable is used by the system to find executables, like `findstr`, so you must not overwrite it; use a different variable name instead.

Here is the way I would probably do it (supposing any text following the keyword `FROM` needs to be returned also):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\MyFolder" & rem // (root directory of the tree to find files)
set "_FILE=MyFile.txt"  & rem // (name of the files to find in the tree)
set "_WORD=FROM"        & rem // (keyword to be searched within the files)
set "_CHAR=;"           & rem // (character to be searched within the files)

rem // Walk through the directory tree and find matching files:
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S "%_ROOT%\%_FILE%"') do (
    rem // Retrieve the line number of each occurrence of the keyword:
    for /F "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /N /I /R "\<%_WORD%\>" "%%~F"') do (
        rem // Process each occurrence of the keyword in a sub-routine:
        call :PROCESS "%%~F" %%N
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS
rem // Ensure the line number to be numeric and build `skip` option string:
set /A "SKIP=%~2-1"
if %SKIP% GTR 0 (set "SKIP=skip^=%SKIP%") else set "SKIP="
rem // Read file starting from line containing the found keyword:
set "FRST=#"
for /F usebackq^ %SKIP%^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%~1") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Split off everything up to the keyword from the first iterated line:
    if defined FRST set "LINE=!LINE:*%_WORD%=!"
    rem /* Split read line at the first occurrence of the split character;
    rem    the line string is augmented by preceding and appending a space,
    rem    so it is possible to detect whether a split char. is there: */
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=%_CHAR% eol=%_CHAR%" %%S in (" !LINE! ") do (
        endlocal
        set "TEXT=%%S"
        set "RMND=%%T"
        set "ITEM=%~1"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Check whether a split character is included in the line string:
        if not defined RMND (
            rem // No split char. found, so get string without surrounding spaces:
            set "TEXT=!TEXT:~1,-1!"
        ) else (
            rem // Split char. found, so get string without leading space:
            set "TEXT=!TEXT:~1!"
        )
        rem // Trimm leading white-spaces:
        for /F "tokens=*" %%E in ("!TEXT!") do (
            endlocal
            set "TEXT=%%E"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        rem // Return string in case it is not empty:
        if defined TEXT echo(!ITEM!;!TEXT!
        rem // Leave sub-routine in case split char. has been found:
        if defined RMND exit /B
    )
    endlocal
    set "FRST="
)
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying to adapt your code to fit my needs, In order to put my results into a text file I redirected the output to log.txt, and added the path of the folder we loop through, like this :  echo(%%~F;!TEXT:~1,-1!)>> log.txt . Is it OK? As you precised it works when FROM key word is in a separate line, my real need is to skip no lines. When I mess with Skip otions I'm getting bizarre results. wich option should I change?

Comment: I changed the script slightly to include the current file path in the output. To log the result, simply redirect the entire batch script, like `script.bat > log.txt` (use `>>` to append rather than to overwrite). So you want the line containing `FROM` to be included in the output as well?

Comment: Yes I would like to include all the string following the "FROM" weither it is in the same line or in a separate line. The parsed file is a code file (QlikView Code),
and depending on how the developper indented the code, the string following the "FROM" can be placed in the same line, like that : FROM [somewhere in the disk] ; . Or lines after, if he put some line breaks.
FROM

[somewhere in the disk] ;

Comment: See my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41289488/4), which should reflect all of your requirements now...